# SQL Create row in table2 when a new insert happens on table1

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-trigger

I have a table `appointments(id,time,patientID,doctorID,daignosis)`
and a table `medical_folder(id,patientID,cure,drug_id)` in PostgreSQL

I want to make a trigger and a function that when there is a new appointment with a diagnosis, it inserts a new row in `medical_folder` with a new id, the patientID(from appointments),cure=XXX and drug_id=YYY

Comment: This is called a trigger.  You should start with the documentation for a trigger in whatever database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Example to start with trigger (MSSQL)

```
CREATE TABLE appointments 
(id int, 
patientId int, 
doctorId int, 
diagnostics varchar(200))
GO

CREATE TABLE medical_folder
(id int, 
patientId int, 
cure int, 
drug_id int)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER InsteadTrigger on appointments
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO medical_folder
       SELECT ISNULL((SELECT MAX(id) from medical_folder),0)+1, patientId, 0, 0
       FROM inserted
END;
GO

INSERT INTO appointments
VALUES 
(1,1,1,'YES')

GO 

SELECT * FROM medical_folder
```